# PHP post does not take the value of a button tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have in a `login.php` the code to check if the user exist or not and also an AJAX call, I have in the form a button tag; If I use `type='submit'` the PHP works but not the AJAX; and if I use `type='button'` the AJAX works but not the PHP.

I've also tried with input but it's the same:

```
    <?php 
     if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
               include "php/conexion.php";
                try {


                $user = $_POST['user'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];


                $sql = 'SELECT count(user_name) FROM user WHERE user_name=:usuario AND password=:password';
                $query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(":usuario", $user);
                $query->bindParam(":password", $pass);
                $query->execute();


                if($res = $query->fetch()) 
                {
                        header("refresh:0.1;url=main.php");
                        }else{
                    echo"User or Password incorrect";
                }

            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $a= $ex->getMessage();
                var_dump($a);
                die();
            }
        }

        ?>


            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
            function realizaProceso(user,pass){
            $.ajax({
                    data:  {"user" : user, "pass": pass},
                    url:   'php/functions_sql.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    success:  function(output) {
                      }
            });
    }
           </script>

     <div class="container">
  <div class="login-container">
            </div>
            <div class="form-box">
                <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <input name="user" id="user" type="text" placeholder="User">
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="button" id="enviar" name="enviar" onclick="realizaProceso($('#user').val(),$('#pass').val());" >Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Move the PHP code to another file, then call it with Ajax.

Comment: then I'll have to do 2 ajax calls ?

Comment: Detect whether the call was made with AJAX, and respond accordingly: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent your form from submitting, to allow your AJAX call to execute. Make the following change to your code:

`onclick="realizaProceso($('#user').val(),$('#pass').val()); return false;"`

The `return false;` statement tells the HTML form to 'stop' the execution of the form submission to allow you to perform a custom action instead, such as an AJAX form submission. That is why your form seems to fail when using `type='submit'`

Your AJAX call also appears to be calling 'php/functions_sql.php'. Are you sure you want your AJAX making a call to what appears to be (based on its title) a Helper class containing SQL related methods?

I am concerned you are posting to 'functions_sql.php', which probably isn't designed to read those variables.

Everything within `if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) { ... }` appears to be a login script (and reads variables). You appear to be mixing 'asynchronous' (AJAX) and 'non-asynchronous' usages together, which is why you are getting confused.

Move that code into a separate file (login_auth.php, for example), then change your AJAX call to talk to it specifically (`$.ajax({ ... , url: 'login_auth.php'}`)

Comment: Yes it contains sql methods, but I need to pass some variables to this file and this is the way I know, Do yo advice me another way?

Comment: I've moved my comment response into my answer

Comment: well that's work ^__^ I'll change it to another file . thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PHP checks for `$_POST['enviar']`, but the AJAX call doesn't put that in the `data:` option. Use:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { user: user, pass: pass, enviar: 1 },
    url:   'php/functions_sql.php',
    type:  'post',
    success:  function(output) {
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not call ajax :(

Comment: Are you using `type="button"` or `type="submit"`? If you use `type="submit"`, clicking on the button does a normal submission unless you do `event.preventDefault()`. That reloads the page and the AJAX is lost.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `button`, use `<input type='button' ....`

It has to be an input field to work properly cross browsers